# Batch Program Typing Words Itself

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch program that opens up, pretends to type some commands, then closes itself all within a few seconds. This program is just to mess around with my friends. If you can help, please make the answer simple, as I am new to batch... Here is my code. I just want to know how to make it close once it finishes.

```
@echo off
::Ghost Typer
title Terminal
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set lines=6


set "line1=c:/launch program hack.exe"
set "line2=c:/sudo program; f1=true"
set "line3=c:/sendttp 192.168.1.351"
set "line4=c:/confirm; admin(host)=true"
set "line5=c:/cipher localhost -n <2"
set "line6=c:/kill appid 67"


for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"

for /L %%a in (1,1,%lines%) do set num=0&set "line=!line%%a!"&call :type

pause>nul
goto :E0F

:type
set "letter=!line:~%num%,1!"
set "delay=%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%"
set "delay=%delay:~-6%"
if not "%letter%"=="" set /p "=a%bs%%letter%" <nul

for /L %%b in (1,60,%delay%) do rem
if "%letter%"=="" echo.&goto :E0F
set /a num+=1
goto :type

:E0F
```

Comment: It _does_ close once it finishes... if you're just looking to get rid of the need to press any key to continue once the typing is done, simply remove the `pause>nul` line.

Comment: Thanks so much! I found the script online and didn't know what to do.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is staying open because of `pause>nul`.

`Pause` ordinarily displays "Press any key to continue..." and then waits for input. It's not doing this right now because of the `>nul`, which means "takes whatever is sent to STDOUT and don't display it" (it's like /dev/null if you have any *NIX knowledge).

Simply remove the line to have the script exit after the typing section is complete.